# Whether every algebra norm $\left|\cdot\right|$ on $C(X)$ is equivalent to uniform norm $\left|\cdot\right|_X$

Tags: banach-algebras

Suppose that $X$ be a compact space and  $\left|\cdot\right|$ be an algebra norm on  $C(X)$

> Is every algebra  norm $\left|\cdot\right|$  on  $C(X)$  equivalent to uniform norm $\left|\cdot\right|_X$?

I don't know where to start. Any clues?

Comment: By "algebra norm" do you mean "Banach algebra norm"?

Comment: @Robert Israel, not necessary Banach

Comment: So just submultiplicative?

Comment: @ Robert Israel , yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to use $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_X$ for the two norms. The identity map from $(C(X), \|\cdot\|)$ to $(C(X), \|\cdot\|_X)$ is nonexpansive. That is,
$|f(x)| \leq \|f\|$ for all $f \in C(X)$ and $x \in X$; this is just because evaluating at $x$ is a complex homomorphism and hence must take $f$ to some point in its spectrum, which is contained in the disk of radius $\|f\|$ about the origin by the spectral radius formula.

Thus, the identity map fails to be an equivalence if and only if the reverse map from $(C(X), \|\cdot\|_X)$ to $(C(X), \|\cdot\|)$ is unbounded. By the Banach isomorphism theorem, this is the same as asking whether there exists an incomplete algebra norm on $C(X)$. If $X$ is any infinite compact Hausdorff space, then Dales and Esterle showed that the continuum hypothesis implies the existence of an incomplete algebra norm on $C(X)$, and Woodin showed that $\neg$CH plus Martin's axiom implies that there is no incomplete algebra norm on $C(X)$. I believe both results are covered in the book *An Introduction to Independence for Analysts* by Dales and Woodin.